# Module with cron job to fetch all products where custom attribute is true

Tags: module, model, eav, resource-model, entities

I am brand new to Magento module development, and I need some help getting started. My goal is relatively simple: I'd like to create a module which fetches all products with a custom attribute 'amazon_ready' set to true, saves these out to a file, and then sets that attribute for all those products back to false. I'd like this to happen every 24 hours.

So far, I have set up a simple cron module using the example found [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html).

```
<?php
namespace SuttersMill\AmazonCron\Cron;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Test {
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
       * Write to system.log
       *
       * @return void
       */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->logger->info('Cron Works');
        // Code to pull in product entities from datastore.
    }
}
```

How do I get all products where the custom attribute is set to true? Any pointers in the right direction would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE, please ask a single question at a time if you want a specific answer. Follow this guide https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to fetch a product collection and filter it based on your custom attribute. You can also fetch most (but not all) of attributes from filter collection items.

Try following code ;

```
<?php
namespace SuttersMill\AmazonCron\Cron;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Test {
    protected $logger;
    protected $collectionFactory;
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger,\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
       * Write to system.log
       *
       * @return void
       */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->logger->info('Cron Works');
        // Code to pull in product entities from datastore.
        $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        /** Apply filters here */
        $filteredProducts = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code',attribute_value);
         foreach($filteredProducts as $product){
            $this->logger->info('  ' .$product->getName() . '  ' );
          }
    }
}
```

Above should print name of the products you want in your logs after you replace attribute_code to the attribute code of your custom attribute and attribute_value to required value (true in your case ).

Feel free to ask any queries if required.

Comment: Np , you can post other questions you were asking in this question as  separate questions too.

Comment: Ok. I will try my best on my own but if I get stuck I will post more questions. Thanks again.